# How big is wchar_t with GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, macros

GCC supports -fshort-wchar that switches wchar_t from 4, to two bytes.

What is the best way to detect the size of wchar_t at compile time, so I can map it correctly to the appropriate utf-16 or utf-32 type?
At least, until c++0x is released and gives us stable utf16_t and utf_32_t typedefs.

```
#if ?what_goes_here?
  typedef wchar_t Utf32;
  typedef unsigned short Utf16;
#else
  typedef wchar_t Utf16;
  typedef unsigned int Utf32;
#endif
```

Comment: Don't do this. wchar_t has nothing to do with unicode. It is a distinct type which can hold all members of the largest extended character set of all supported locales. If your platform supports only ASCII then sizeof(wchar_t) can be 1. This also means that, for example, that L'mötley crüe' is *not necessarily* an unicode string - it could as well be a Latin-1 string stored with wchar_t.

Comment: That is the most universally unhelpful comment ever. On the basis of that advice we should never attempt to deal with a Utf encoded string until C++0x is universally released. In the meantime, I need a set of typedefs, for the platforms I support, that map to the most appropriate distinct types that can hold the data required.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the macros

```
__WCHAR_MAX__
__WCHAR_TYPE__
```

They are defined by gcc. You can check their value with `echo "" | gcc -E - -dM`

As the value of `__WCHAR_TYPE__` can vary from `int` to `short unsigned int` or `long int`, the best for your test is IMHO to check if `__WCHAR_MAX__` is above 2^16.

```
#if __WCHAR_MAX__ > 0x10000
  typedef ...
#endif
```

Comment: Im marking this as the answer, as it is the closest to what I was looking for. The template magic in the other answer does seem an even more clever way to support more platforms without knowing lots of platform specific macro's

Answer (score 13):

```
template<int>
struct blah;

template<>
struct blah<4> {
  typedef wchar_t Utf32;
  typedef unsigned short Utf16;
};

template<>
struct blah<2> {
  typedef wchar_t Utf16;
  typedef unsigned int Utf32;
};

typedef blah<sizeof(wchar_t)>::Utf16 Utf16;
typedef blah<sizeof(wchar_t)>::Utf32 Utf32;
```

Comment: Why would you assume that an unsigned short is 2 bytes wide and an unsigned int 4 bytes, and then not simply unconditionally typedef them? You're using your assumptions halfheartedly ...

Comment: @etarion: I simply answered the question.  Wchar_t is a distinct type in C++ (I can't recall for C) and the OP (apparently) wants to use it.

Comment: This is a hugely clever way of using c++ to avoid #ifdef magic. That said, it does pollute the global namespace.

Comment: @ChrisBecke: You can put blah (or utf_types :P) in a "detail" namespace, similar to how Boost hides implementation details.  Hopefully the whole thing (including the last Utf16/32 typedefs) are also wrapped in a namespace for your project.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the standard macro: `WCHAR_MAX`:

```
#include <wchar.h>
#if WCHAR_MAX > 0xFFFFu
// ...
#endif
```

`WCHAR_MAX` Macro was defined by **ISO C** and  **ISO C++** standard (see: ISO/IEC 9899 - 7.18.3 Limits of other integer types and ISO/IEC 14882 - C.2), so you could use it safely on almost all compilers.

Comment: if `WCHAR_MAX` is defined in the ISO standards, you can use it safely on *all* compilers (since anything that doesn't define `WCHAR_MAX`, is technically neither a C nor a C++ compiler).

Answer (score 4):

The size depends on the compiler flag -fshort-wchar:

```
g++ -E -dD -fshort-wchar -xc++ /dev/null | grep WCHAR
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ short unsigned int
#define __WCHAR_MAX__ 0xffff
#define __WCHAR_MIN__ 0
#define __WCHAR_UNSIGNED__ 1
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_WCHAR_T_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ 2
#define __ARM_SIZEOF_WCHAR_T 4
```

Answer (score 2):

As Luther Blissett said, wchar_t exists independently from Unicode - they are two different things.

If you are really talking about UTF-16 - be aware that there are unicode characters which map to two 16-bit words (U+10000..U+10FFFF, although these are rarely used in western countries/languages).

Comment: Nowadays there is heavy usage in that range for emoji and alike.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ g++ -E -dD -xc++ /dev/null | grep WCHAR
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ int
#define __WCHAR_MAX__ 2147483647
#define __WCHAR_MIN__ (-__WCHAR_MAX__ - 1)
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_WCHAR_T_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ 4
```