# libpcre2 Code Unit Width

Tags: unicode, utf-8, pcre

I've been looking at the man page for `pcre2`, and trying to figure out precisely what situations require which definitions of `PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH`.

> The source code for PCRE2 can be compiled to support 8-bit, 16-bit, or
>   32-bit code units, which means that up to three separate libraries may
>   be installed.

**Question 1**: What exactly is PCRE2's code unit? Does this mean I need to use `PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 8` to handle `char*` versus `PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 32` for `wchar *` ? what if my platform's `wchar` is 16-bit? would that require conditionally using `PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 16`? If this is true, it seems like according to [How big is wchar_t with GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873565) I would need to use the `PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH = 8 * __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__`

On the topic of Unicode:

> In all three cases, strings can be interpreted either as one character per code unit, or as UTF-encoded Unicode, with support for Unicode general category properties. Unicode support is optional at build time (but is the default). However, processing strings as UTF code units must be enabled explicitly at run time.

**Question 2**: What exactly does PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH mean when Unicode is enabled? Does `PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 8` take UTF-8, and I need to set `PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 16` to handle a UTF-16 string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What exactly is PCRE2's code unit?

Here's what PCRE2 uses for its code unit definitions (in `pcre2.h`):

```c
/* Types for code units in patterns and subject strings. */

typedef uint8_t  PCRE2_UCHAR8;
typedef uint16_t PCRE2_UCHAR16;
typedef uint32_t PCRE2_UCHAR32;

typedef const PCRE2_UCHAR8  *PCRE2_SPTR8;
typedef const PCRE2_UCHAR16 *PCRE2_SPTR16;
typedef const PCRE2_UCHAR32 *PCRE2_SPTR32;
```

So you can see that PCRE2 uses `uintX_t` under the hood instead of `char`/`wchar_t`.

Note that when you define `PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH` to 8, 16 or 32, `PCRE2_UCHAR` and `PCRE2_SPTR` will be #defined to the correct variant.

So yes, `PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH = 8 * __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__` seems reasonable at first glance, **but** [`wchar_t` is not meant to handle Unicode data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259544/is-wchar-t-needed-for-unicode-support). Avoid it if you want to write portable code, and just use `char`/`uint8_t` for UTF-8, `uint16_t` for UTF-16 and `uint32_t` for UTF-32.

Don't confuse *code units* with *code points*, as several code units can be required to encode a single code point.

> What exactly does `PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH` mean when Unicode is enabled? Does `PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 8` take UTF-8, and I need to set `PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 16` to handle a UTF-16 string?

Yes. You can also set `PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH` to 0 if you need to handle several encodings in your program. You'll lose the aliases like `pcre2_match`, and you'll have to call `pcre2_match_8` or `pcre2_match_16` for instance.